# Borderless window in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

I want to have Borderless window similar to image I have attached; how can I do this ?

Thanks
Ocean[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get rid of the default chrome by making the window transparent and windowStyle to None, and need to provide styled buttons instead of the regular buttons on the top-right

```
<Window  WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid issues like windows covering the taskbar when maximized, etc. use the [Microsoft WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell)

Answer (score 0):

I also have some code that I wrote a little bit ago which **I THINK** covers all the basic windowing problems, from snapping, to unsnapping, maximizing on proper monitor, not covering task bar, etc.  Take a look at it.

[WPF Borderless Window issues: Aero Snap & Maximizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422666/wpf-borderless-window-issues-aero-snap-maximizing/48626016#48626016)