# WPF Borderless Window issues: Aero Snap & Maximizing

Tags: c#, wpf, aero, wndproc

I've created a borderless WPF window by setting the following window properties in XAML:

```
... WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ...
```

**This causes a number of issues:**

**1) Resolved:** It no longer has any built-in resize functionality

**2) Resolved:** It no longer has any built-in drag functionality

**3) Resolved:** Without the top toolbar, it no longer has minimize/maximize/restore/close buttons

**4) Resolved:** Maximizing via aero snap or setting WindowState prevents it from unsnapping.

**5)** Maximizing via aero snap or setting WindowState will use the whole screen as the boundary, overlapping the windows toolbar.

**6)** Maximizing via aero snap or setting WindowState seems to include a -7 margin, giving the window 7 pixels on each side that are beyond the edges of the window.

1-3 were solved by making a xaml window template. I used invisible rectangles as handle regions, and some code behind that was applied via overriding OnApplyTemplate() to attach functionality via user32.dll SendMessage(...) for resize/move/minimize/maximize/restore/close.

I found the answer to # 4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703833/dragmove-and-maximize)

I tried solving 5-6 by intercepting the maximize message via WndProc and setting the size/position manually, but this had the issue of overwriting the RestoreRegion to the maximized size/position, removing the ability to restore the window.

What's really odd is that resizing the window from the top border to the top of the screen triggers the aero full height snap just fine, with no issues at all.

So, I've come a long way, but 5-6 is still an issue... is there a way to manually specify the maximize region? Or, is there a way to set the window size without affecting the restoreregion property?

Comment: It would be nice if you add your solution 1-4 in a answer..

Comment: seconded, I would very much like to have the answer for #4

Comment: Solution to "4" i think this one is good.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432873/11912872

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Easiest Full Solution

Hello, The following solution fixes all of the issues detailed in your question in the simplest manner possible, and works on Windows 10 using WPF and the latest version of the C# language and .NET framework. This is as of 3/15/2017. Please let me know if it stops working.

**Step 1:** To address issues 1, 2, and 4, within your `<Window ... > </Window>` tags in the XAML of your application, paste this in, at the top or bottom:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35"/>
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

`CaptionHeight` is the desired height of your window dragging area.

**Step 2:** To address issue 3, you need to create your title bar and caption as well as the window controls. To do this, you simply need to give the desired title bar elements each a VerticalAlignment of Top, or put them into a grid with it's VerticalAlignment set to Top, which will do it for all of them, but make sure that their heights are not greater than the `CaptionHeight` property on the `WindowChrome` element declared in the XAML, from step 1. For all the buttons, you must assign them, or their container, the property `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`. Here is an example:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Name="TitleBar" Height="35">
    <Label Content="Borderless Window Test" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <StackPanel WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Name="WindowControls">
        <Button Height="35" Width="35" Content="-" Padding="0" Name="MinimizeButton"/>
        <Button Height="35" Width="35" Content="+" Padding="0" Name="MaximizeButton"/>
        <Button Height="35" Width="35" Content="x" Padding="0" Name="CloseButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, to add proper functionality to the window control buttons, within the `MainWindow()` constructor of your codebehind, the C# source code of your application, paste the following in, **after** the call to `InitializeComponent();`:

```
CloseButton.Click += (s, e) => Close();
MaximizeButton.Click += (s, e) => WindowState = WindowState == WindowState.Normal ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
MinimizeButton.Click += (s, e) => WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

**Step 3:** To address issues 5 and 6, you need to hook into WmGetMinMaxInfo. To do this, go to your codebehind, then copy and paste everything from this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WDZpDKRN) into your Window class. Now, within your `MainWindow()` constructor, paste:

```
SourceInitialized += (s, e) =>
{
    IntPtr handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
    HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
};
```

Via `Project > Add References` in the file menu, be sure to have references to:

```
System.Management
System.Windows.Interop
System.Security.Principal
System.Runtime.InteropServices
Microsoft.Win32
```

The best way to check is to click on the `Assemblies` tab in the top left, then select `Framework`, then use the search box in the top right corner of the window. Now add all of these usings (namespaces) to the top of your codebehind:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

That should cover everything. I hope this helps!

Comment: While I personally believe that reference to `Microsoft.Win32` should be avoided (for portability reasons, if nothing else), I do appreciate this answer. I knew about `WindowChrome`, but only your post made me realize that it way simpler to use than I thought.

Comment: Not entirely perfect in a multi monitor with different resolution setting, but by far the better solution found so far ! I really liked the WindowChrome stuff in particular

Comment: I've tested this on my computer that runs one 4K monitor and one 1080p monitor and it works beautify! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I just went through this entire thing myself.  It was a real chore, because you have to manually account for so much.  It's funny, we take so much for granted these days, with something as simple as how a basic window operates.  But a look at this sample code that I am providing is a good indication of just how much really goes into this problem.

I hope this helps, as it took me a little time to get here myself.

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    Background="Transparent"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test Window Behavior" Height="768" Width="1024" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">

<Grid>
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <DockPanel x:Name="titleBar" Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Rectangle Width="32" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Red" Margin="2"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2">

                <!-- Minimize Button -->
                <Border Width="24" Height="24" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMinimizeWindow" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD0D0D0" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="0" FontFamily="Webdings" />
                </Border>

                <!-- Maximize Button -->
                <Border Width="24" Height="24" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMaximizeWindow" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD0D0D0" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="IsMaximized" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Webdings">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="1" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=InternalWindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Maximized">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="2" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>

                <!-- Close Button -->
                <Border Width="24" Height="24" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnCloseWindow" Grid.Column="4">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="r" FontFamily="Webdings" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

            <Label MouseLeftButtonDown="OnDragMoveWindow" MouseDoubleClick="OnMaximizeWindow" Margin="8 0 0 0" FontSize="12" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, FallbackValue='Main Window'}" />
        </DockPanel>

        <Grid Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="32">
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Statusbar Text Goes Here ..." />
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Top 3 -->
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

            <!-- Middle 2 -->
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 1 0" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" />

            <!-- Bottom 3 -->
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border Background="Transparent" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Top/Left -->
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="4" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Tag="0" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Tag="0" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!-- Top/Right -->
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="4" Cursor="SizeNESW" Tag="0" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNESW" Tag="0" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!-- Bottom/Left -->
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="4" Cursor="SizeNESW" Tag="1" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNESW" Tag="1" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!-- Bottom/Right -->
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="4" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Tag="1" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
            <Thumb DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Tag="1" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!-- Left -->
        <Thumb Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="4" Cursor="SizeWE" Tag="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />

        <!-- Top -->
        <Thumb Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNS" Tag="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />

        <!-- Right -->
        <Thumb Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="4" Cursor="SizeWE" Tag="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />

        <!-- Bottom -->
        <Thumb Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="4" Cursor="SizeNS" Tag="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region --- Declarations ---
        private Rect _location { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region --- Constructors ---
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion

        #region --- Properties ---
        private Rect DesktopArea
        {
            get
            {
                var c = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
                var s = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromPoint(c);
                var a = s.WorkingArea;
                return new Rect(a.Left, a.Top, a.Width, a.Height);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region --- Dependency Properties ---
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalWindowStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InternalWindowState", typeof(WindowState), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(WindowState.Normal, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnInternalWindowStateChanged)));

        public WindowState InternalWindowState
        {
            get { return (WindowState)GetValue(InternalWindowStateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InternalWindowStateProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnInternalWindowStateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow instance = (MainWindow)d;
            instance.SetInternalWindowState((WindowState)e.NewValue);
        }
        #endregion

        #region --- Private Methods ---
        private void StoreLocation()
        {
            _location = new Rect(this.Left, this.Top, this.Width, this.Height);
        }

        private void RestoreLocation()
        {
            this.Width = _location.Width;
            this.Height = _location.Height;
            this.Top = _location.Top >= 0 ? _location.Top : 0;
            this.Left = _location.Left;
        }

        private void SetMaximizedState()
        {
            this.Width = DesktopArea.Width;
            this.Height = DesktopArea.Height;
            this.Top = DesktopArea.Top;
            this.Left = DesktopArea.Left;
        }

        private void SetInternalWindowState(WindowState state)
        {
            InternalWindowState = state;

            switch (InternalWindowState)
            {
                case WindowState.Normal:
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    RestoreLocation();
                    break;
                case WindowState.Maximized:
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    SetMaximizedState();
                    break;
                case WindowState.Minimized:
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    break;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region --- Sizing Routines --- 
        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Thumb thumb = (Thumb)sender;
            int tag = Convert.ToInt32(thumb.Tag);
            if (thumb.Cursor == Cursors.SizeWE) HandleSizeWE(tag, e);
            if (thumb.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNS) HandleSizeNS(tag, e);
            if (thumb.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNESW) HandleSizeNESW(tag, e);
            if (thumb.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNWSE) HandleSizeNWSE(tag, e);
        }

        private void HandleSizeNWSE(int tag, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tag == 0)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }

        private void HandleSizeNESW(int tag, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tag == 0)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }

        private void HandleSizeNS(int tag, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tag == 0)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
            }
            else
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
        }

        private void HandleSizeWE(int tag, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tag == 0)
            {
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
            }
            else
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
        }
        #endregion

        #region --- Event Handlers ---
        private void OnDragMoveWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InternalWindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                var c = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
                this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                this.Height = _location.Height;
                this.Width = _location.Width;
                this.Top = c.Y - (titleBar.ActualHeight / 2);
                this.Left = c.X - (_location.Width / 2);
            }
            this.DragMove();
        }

        private void OnMaximizeWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InternalWindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            else
                this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void OnMinimizeWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void OnCloseWindow(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.InternalWindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InternalWindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
                StoreLocation();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent work, works fine for me. -- There's a minor bug that is occurring here when I double-click the TitleBar, the Window maximizes and restores to its normal size. I tried to fix, but failed. (I am using Windows 10 with 2 screen monitors (displays))

Comment: Very good because was very easy to implement. I just had to install some references like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639468/forms-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-windows

Answer (score 3):

For Point number 5, use this:

```
public WindowName() // Constructor for your window
{
this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
}
```

This will ensure that the window will not overlap the taskbar when maximized.

Comment: This only works if (a) you have only one monitor, and (b) the taskbar is on the bottom edge of your monitor.  Any other configuration and it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the maximize region by handling the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` Win32 message. The code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx) shows how to do that. It will solve issues #5 and #6.

Note that there are a few things that I would do differently, such as returning `IntPtr.Zero` instead of (System.IntPtr)0 in WindowProc and making `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` a constant. But that's just coding style changes, and doesn't affect the net result.

Also make sure to pay attention to the update where the `WindowProc` is hooked during the `SourceInitialized` event instead of `OnApplyTemplate`. That's the better place to do it. If you're implementing a class derived from Window, then another option is to override `OnSourceInitialized` to hook the `WindowProc` instead of attaching to the event. That's what I normally do.

Answer (score 1):

for all these problems, I can only recommend this:

MahApps.Metro: http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Sourcecode: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

it's a nice library with a nice theme and easy to use!

hope that helps

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but I'll look at the source code when I have a chance. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response, but I was dealing with these exact issues a couple of years back, especially #6.

For #6, this is an issue if you have ResizeState set to CanResize or CanResizeWithGrip, CanMinimize and NoResize fullscreens with no overscan. What I have done is I created my own titlebar with minimize, maximize, close and DragMove (with unsnapping support) functionality and I have created a thumb as the resize grip to allow resizing.

This still have a few drawbacks like only being able to resize from the bottom right corner and having to deal with #5. I haven't found an elegant solution for this one yet.