# Borderless Window with full functionality

Tags: c#, wpf

For a while now I have attempted to get into UI design with WPF. My main goal is to create a good-looking application in a borderless window, like for example:

[image: borderless window]

I made this example using the MetroUI framework. While this framework does the trick on borderless window functionality, it also does *way* too much for my tastes, custom controls, skins, animations, etc. I just want a borderless window and decide everything else myself.

I've searched stackoverflow a lot, and tried a fair amount of frameworks, but nothing seems to suit my needs.

Basically, I would like to have a borderless window with FULL windows functionality (drag to sides to pin, only show shadow if operating system settings has it on, etc etc).

Putting WindowStyle to None but keeping AllowsTransparency at False in order to preserve the original window chrome makes most if not all of the functionality I am seeking for work. However, the obvious problem here is: the window chrome is still there.

This looks like this:

[image: form with windowstyle none]

**To finally ask my  question:**

Can we keep all the current functionality that this window chrome provides, but somehow make it invisible (yet keep the dropshadow it provides) ? I can live without the dropshadow but it would be a nice bonus.

Or to ask a more broad question: is there any framework / pre-made project, that simply ONLY handles making a borderless window work properly and no other additional controls, skinning, ... ?

The more time I put into this the more it seems making borderless windows with WPF is simply incredibly clunky and I am getting rather unmotivated on my entire project because of this.

Thank you

Comment: mahapp metro Window has all the functionality for window. what happen if you use it ?

Comment: I mentioned in my post I used MetroUI but found it doing a bit too much for my tastes, it automatically adds in all kinds of animations and skins which I rather don't have

Comment: MahApps has fill my needs and you can use the part you need only. Just a quick google found this https://github.com/blachniet/SimpleBorderlessWPFWindow

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on the following thread, it pretty much sums up all the window issues at once.  Hope it helps!

[WPF Borderless Window issues: Aero Snap & Maximizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422666/wpf-borderless-window-issues-aero-snap-maximizing/48626016#48626016)